# Laravel - Update $guarded array based on different config

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have one model and one controller and multiple configurations.

If I'm on config #1 my models `$guarded` property should be

```
$guarded = ['foo', 'bar'];
```

If I'm on config #2 my models `$guarded` property should be only

```
$guarded = ['foo'];
```

The config loaded is dependant on a domain/subdomain.

In my controller I have an import function which takes an array of data. 4 or so of the fields need to go to one table which is common across all configs and the remaining values(which are variable depending on the config loaded) need to go into a separate pivot table. So one config might have 8 fields but another may have 9 or more / less.

I've tried to remove the variable fields from the insert into the first table with guarded with something similar to the code here. After which I take the variable fields and insert into the other table.

```
protected $guarded = ['some', 'common', 'guarded', 'fields'];

function __construct()
{
    $this->guarded = array_merge($this->guarded, config('custom_fields_for_domain'));
}
```

While I can `dd($this->guarded)` directly after and see the variable fields correctly in the model, I receive errors when trying to import into the first table as it's still trying to import all the variable fields rather than just the 4 or so fields I want.

If I manually add in all the variable fields, it works fine, so it seems that modifying `$guarded` even as early on as in the constructor doesn't work. It this correct? Is there a better way to modify the `$guarded` values based on different configurations?

I've not tried yet, but would I be better off using `$fillable` for just the fields I know are constant?

Comment: Have you tried using $model->guard() method that's part of GuardsAttributes trait?

Comment: I've just given it a try with `$model_name->guard(['one_field'])` however I still receive an error indicating the field I passed in is still being added to the insert.